# Counting vowels in a string and wrong output?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I am very new to java and I was wondering if you could help me out. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int vowels = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter a string: ");
        String string = input.nextLine();

    int length = string.length();

for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {

    String letter = string.substring(i, ++i);

    if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){vowels++;}    
    if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){vowels++;}
    if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("i")){vowels++;}
    if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("o")){vowels++;}
    if (letter.equalsIgnoreCase("u")){vowels++;}

}
    System.out.println ("The number of vowels in " + string + " is: " + vowels);
}
```

The number is off but I can't figure out why.

Comment: format the code and make a question

Comment: Off by how much? Is it always consistently wrong? Show us some example input and the corresponding output. As a general suggestion, I'd try adding a bunch more `System.out.println()` statements within the `for` loop. For example, maybe after the `String letter...` line, you could output which letter it's considering and after all the `if` statements, you could output how many vowels it's counted so far. This will probably guide you to the source of the problem.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here is wrong

```
string.substring(i, ++i)
```

because the variable **i** is already incremented in the for-loop

so you are basically skipping chars in the string

---

implement the right logic, use the right data type

```
    int length = string.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char letter = string.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(letter);
        if (letter == 'a') {
            vowels++;
        } else if (letter == 'e') {
            vowels++;
        } else if (letter == 'i') {
            vowels++;
        } else if (letter == 'o') {
            vowels++;
        } else if (letter == 'u') {
            vowels++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I did that but I get zero for the vowels.

Comment: it depends where the vowels are, your logic is making the code to iterate over elements at index 2n+1

Comment: so what do i change it to then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution you could try:

The split method will split the string into a String array. Then in your for loop it will check every item in your array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int vowels = 0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter a string: ");
        String string = input.nextLine();

    int length = string.length();

    String[] stringArray = string.split("");

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {   //I took out the = sign in your for loop arguments.

    if (stringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("a")){vowels++;}    
    if (stringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("e")){vowels++;}
    if (stringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("i")){vowels++;}
    if (stringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("o")){vowels++;}
    if (stringArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("u")){vowels++;}

}
    System.out.println ("The number of vowels in " + string + " is: " + vowels);
}
```